# Web Audio API, Recorder.js: Recording from sourceBuffer without delay

Tags: html, web-audio-api, recorder.js

I am trying to create a Web Audio API based application. So far I have multiple buffer nodes, connected to the destination.

What I trying to achieve is to be able to record the output result when the user (for example) presses a button, I tried using `recorder.js` but as far as I understand you need to play the graph along.

The following code depicts the issue:

```
<html><body><audio controls autoplay></audio>
<script type="text/javascript" src="recorder.js"> </script>
<input onclick="startRecording()" type="button" value="start recording" />
<input onclick="stopRecording()" type="button" value="stop recording and play" />

<script>

var context = new webkitAudioContext();
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

var onFail = function(e) {
  console.log('Rejected!', e);
};

var onSuccess = function(s) {
  request.open('GET', 'voice.wav', true);
  request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

  request.onload = function () {
    var undecodedAudio = request.response;
    context.decodeAudioData(undecodedAudio, function (buffer) {
      // The contents of our mp3 is now an AudioBuffer
      var sourceBuffer = context.createBufferSource();
      sourceBuffer.buffer = buffer;
      sourceBuffer.connect (context.destination);
      recorder = new Recorder(sourceBuffer);
      recorder.record();
      sourceBuffer.start (context.currentTime);
    });
  };

  request.send();
}

window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
navigator.getUserMedia  = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;

var recorder;
var audio = document.querySelector('audio');

function startRecording() {
  if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
    navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true}, onSuccess, onFail);
  } else {
    console.log('navigator.getUserMedia not present');
  }
}

function stopRecording() {
  recorder.stop();
  recorder.exportWAV(function(s) {
    audio.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(s);
  });
}

</script></body></html>
```

What I want is when the user presses recording, the file is converted to resultant audio without actually playback.

Comment: Have you checked out the offlineAudioContext? I think that's what you're looking for. It won't actually render the audio, but just tries to calculate it as fast as possible. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OfflineAudioContext